# Recursividad en java

Tags: java, recursión, bluej

estaba haciendo ejercicios de recursividad y me he topado con este. No entiendo muy bien cómo hacer para que se cuenten las pasadas, ya que cada vez que llamo al método, el valor de la variable "cont" se guarda y da un número erróneo.

> Escribir un método de clase recursivo que, dados dos números naturales a ≥ 0
> y b > 0, calcule el cociente de su división entera, basándose en el hecho de
> que dicha operación se puede realizar como una serie de restas sucesivas (de
> forma similar al problema del cálculo del resto de la división entera de la
> sección 10.4), siguiendo la recurrencia:
> a/b = 0, si a<b 
> a/b = (a − b)/b + 1, si a ≥ b

Este es el código que he escrito:

```
static int cont = 0;
public static int division(int a, int b){
    if(a < b){
        cont++;
        return 0;}
    else{
        division( (a-b) / b + 1, b);  
        cont++;
    }
    return cont;
}
```

Comment: ya intentaste pasarle cont como parametro?

Comment: @DarkIceDust pero entonces cada vez que el método se llama a si mismo "cont" volveria a 0 ¿No?. Por lo que al final devuelve siempre 1.

Comment: @RuslanLópez no entiendo a qué te refieres con pasar "cont" cómo parámetro (soy nuevo en programación).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solo cuando (a>=b) el contador debe aumentar,`a/b = (a − b)/b + 1, si a ≥ b` esto aplica si quisieras devolver el resultado mismo método

```
 return 1+division(a-b, b);
```

pero como estas queriendo devolver el contador como cociente,seria así

```
static int cont = 0;
public static int division(int a, int b){
    if(a < b){

        return 0;

    }else{

       cont++;

        division(a-b, b);  
        
   }
   return cont;
}
```

Comment: Vale, pero hay algo que no entiendo. El propio ejercicio te dice que "a/b = (a − b)/b + 1, si a ≥ b", pero no lo usas en el código ¿Por qué?

Comment: Estas regresando un contador como si fuese el cociente(`return cont`),pero el ejercicio te menciona que el calculo aplica a la recurrencia del método, osea si lo que regresas, es el mismo método (`return division()`) como cociente ,si quieres hacer uso de ese calculo cambia el `return cont` por `return 1+division(a-b,b)` este ultimo es el calculo de la referencia,ambos casos te darán un correcto resultado

Comment: Una apunte, este código si lo ejecutas varias veces da resultados diferentes, creo que es porque "cont" almacena el valor. ¿Alguna idea para que no lo almacene?

Comment: pues al ser static int cont se me ocurre que después de usar el método declares cont =0; para que limpie lo que almaceno, al usar recursividad no se puede declarar cont dentro del metodo ni pasarlo como parametro :s

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias.